# ContentPublication Limit exceeded in Test Class?

Tags: apex, unit-test, contentversion

Is the content publication limit applicable to test class as well? All i am doing on my test class is to create a contentversion record. It still says that  `ContentPublication Limit exceeded`.

Does this mean I cannot run this test class till 24 hour rolling period is finished?

```
@isTest
private class Test_FileProcessorBatch {
  @TestSetup
  static void makeData() {
    Contentversion cv = new Contentversion();
    cv.Title = 'ABC';
    cv.PathOnClient = 'test';
    cv.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(
      EncodingUtil.urlEncode('Unit Test Attachment Body', 'UTF-8')
    );
    insert cv;
  }
}
```

I am not even sure that we have created that many content version in this org. Is there a way to know how many content versions have been created in a day?

Comment: We sometimes encounter this error as well. Usually we rerun the tests and this again disappear. Does this apply to you as well?

Comment: No, i keep getting this error everytime i try to run it

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was a batch process which was creating some content version records during the night and which was causing the limits to be hit. Ended up disabling the scheduled process and next day we are able to run the tests